# How do I get rid of the two bash : lines?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

> bash: /home/falgun/Desktop/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash: No such file or directory
> bash: /usr/share/colcon_cd/function/colcon_cd.sh: No such file or directory
> falgun@falgun-HP-Laptop:~/Desktop$

These show everytime i start the terminal. I want to remove that.

Answer (score 0):

something seems to try to call these two scripts, likely .bash_rc or .profile. to find the script try

```
cd
grep setup.bash .*
grep colcon_cd.sh .*
```

then edit the resulting script, and comment out (#) the calls.